# Slamdata Query Nested Arrays

Tags: mongodb, slamdata

I have the below code as part of a mongodb document that I am querying with Slamdata v4.0:

```
"services" : [
    {
        "serviceline101" : {
            "Name" : "Brake Inspection",
            "Part_Number" : "",
            "QTY" : "6",
            "Notes" : ""
        },
        "serviceline102" : {
            "Name" : "Oil Samples",
            "Part_Number" : "",
            "QTY" : "1",
            "Notes" : ""
        },
        "serviceline103" : {
            "Name" : "Inspection",
            "Part_Number" : "",
            "QTY" : "1",
            "Notes" : ""
        },
```

What I need to do is to be able to query against the second layer of nested data in "services".

I can get to this data for one object by using

```
services[*]
```

or for one object in the array:

```
services[*].serviceline1.Part_Number
```

for instance.

What I am trying to find is a way for this engine to iterate through all objects in the services array down to Part_Number for each like (this doesn't work, just theory):

```
services[*].*.Part_Number
```

Any ideas?  I don't even know if this is possible.  I am currently getting around this by making a flat dataset for reporting purposes only and can continue doing, just trying to eliminate a step if I'm able.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following syntax to flatten the values in a document:

`services[*]{*}.Part_Number`

Hope that helps!

Comment: I thought I'd tried it with curly brackets, but regardless, this time it worked!  Thanks a ton.